# Visual Studio code disable code formatting for object destructuring

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, formatting, tslint, object-destruction

I'm writing web app using Koa and Typescript. In vscode i faced with unwanted code formatting: when i declare variables using object desctructing approach vscode autoformat it in multilines:

```
deleteUser: async (ctx: Context) => {
  const {
    body: { userId }
  } = ctx;

  await userService.deleteUser(userId);
}
```

And i want it in this case remain in a single line:

```
deleteUser: async (ctx: Context) => {
  const { body: { userId } } = ctx;

  await userService.deleteUser(userId);
}
```

I like how vscode handles my code formatting, so i don't want to disable it. But i want to find a workaround to disable object destructuring formatting if line length less than 80 chars.

What rule should i use to fix this ? Should i change vscode rules or tslint rules ?

Here's my .tslint file:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "class-name": true,
    "comment-format": [true, "check-space"],
    "indent": ["tabs"],
    "one-line": [true, "check-open-brace", "check-whitespace"],
    "no-var-keyword": true,
    "quotemark": [true, "double", "avoid-escape"],
    "semicolon": [true, "always", "ignore-bound-class-methods"],
    "max-line-length": [true, 120],
    "whitespace": [
      true,
      "check-branch",
      "check-decl",
      "check-operator",
      "check-module",
      "check-separator",
      "check-type",
      "check-preblock"
    ],
    "typedef-whitespace": [
      true,
      {
        "call-signature": "nospace",
        "index-signature": "nospace",
        "parameter": "nospace",
        "property-declaration": "nospace",
        "variable-declaration": "nospace"
      },
      {
        "call-signature": "onespace",
        "index-signature": "onespace",
        "parameter": "onespace",
        "property-declaration": "onespace",
        "variable-declaration": "onespace"
      }
    ],
    "no-internal-module": true,
    "no-trailing-whitespace": true,
    "no-null-keyword": true,
    "prefer-const": true,
    "jsdoc-format": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can install beautify plugin and add following config in vscode's settings.json.

```
"beautify.config": {
    "brace_style": "collapse,preserve-inline"
}
```